# windows form combo box problem?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am writing windows from application in that i am using combo box control. I have already inserted data in combo box. some properties i have sated for combo box are

dropdownstyle= dropdown
autocompletesource = Listitem
autocompletemode= suggested append.

now my problem is i would like to restrict user to enter only those value which is in combo box.
for example if combo box has 3 item in it 
apple, mango and grape

then i want user to enter one of them while they filling value in combo box.

thank you guys for time.
Vijay shiyani

Comment: Why do you want to let the user enter their own values? Why not just let them select from the items in the combo box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to validate their selection by checking if the combo boxe's [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) is anything other than -1. If it is then they have typed or selected an item out of the list. You can also do a similar thing by checking if the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) != null.

eg.

```
if (comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
   // Item from list selected
}
else
{
   // Error: please selecte an item from the list
}
```

Another way to avoid validation is to set the [ComboBoxStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx) to DropDownList, which will still allow them to type but will only allow them to type or select an item from the list.

Answer (score 3):

Change DropDownStyle to DropDownList instead of DropDown

```
combobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

or change it in the VS properties page

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event of the ComboBox:

```
var cbo = (ComboBox)sender;
if (cbo.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

**NOTE:** Setting the Cancel to true prevents the user from leaving the control being validated.
Use with extreme caution.

Comment: it wont work because selectedItem is object and we cannot compare it with int value -1.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I was rather referring to the `SelectedIndex` property. See the update.